# Scree Plot Using Eigenvalues in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, eigenvalues

What is the best way to generate a Scree Plot (for Scree Test) using the Eigenvalues from the PCA?

Here is what I am using right now:

```
(X = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2000, 4000}]) // TableForm;
mu = Mean[X] + 0.0;
(Z = (# - mu) & /@ X ) + 0.0 // TableForm;
c = Covariance[Z];
v = Eigenvalues[c];
ListLinePlot[Accumulate[v]/Total[v], PlotRange -> {All, All}]
```

Comment: Do you have a dataset to play with? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MarcoB, I updated the question.

Comment: @Saquib Your code has some features I don't understand, e.g. the use of `TableForm` when output is suppressed anyway, and the addition of `0.0` quantities. Nevertheless, it seems to me that all you need is `Normalize[v, Total]` instead of your `Accumulate[v] / Total[v]` expression. Note also that you may want to try this out on a smaller data set, e.g. $200x400$: the one you generate is rather large.

Comment: There's no need to subtract the mean, as the covariance is independent of the mean. Just do `v = Eigenvalues[Covariance[X]]`.

Answer (score 4):

Putting all of the above comments together:

```
X = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {200, 400}];
v = Eigenvalues[Covariance[X]];
ListPlot[Normalize[v, Total], PlotRange -> All,
  AxesLabel -> {"eigenvalue index", "fraction of variance"}]
```

[image]

If you insist on accumulating the eigenvalues,

```
ListPlot[Normalize[Accumulate[v], Last], PlotRange -> All,
  AxesLabel -> {"eigenvalue index", "cumulative fraction of variance"}]
```

[image]